# Java Поиск кратчайшего пути в графе для всех вершин смежных 0

Tags: java, алгоритм, графы

Всем привет. Есть следующий граф:

[image: не отсортированный граф]

Граф читается сверху вниз, слева направо.

Где 0 - это пустая ячейка, которая используется для перестановки вершин графа к исходному виду:

[image: Отсортированный граф]

Иначе говоря граф 2 1 3 4 0 5 6 7 нужно привести к виду 1 2 3 4 0 5 6 7, а выводом программы должен являться массив ходов
5 3 2 1 2 3 5 , минимальная последовательность ходов перемещения вершин в пустую ячейку до сортировки в исходное состояние.

Причем передача в метод  графа 1 2 3 4 0 5 6 7  должна возвращать пустой массив int[]{}.

есть код, класс Граф с поиском по ширине :

```
java
package ru.job4j.puzzle;

import java.util.Arrays;

class Graph {
    private final int[][] matrix;
    private final int[] v;
    private boolean[] visit;

    Graph(int[][] matrix, int[] v) {
        this.matrix = matrix;
        this.v = v;
        this.visit = new boolean[v.length];
    }

    private int getIndexNextV(int indexV) {
        int result = -1;
        for (int index = 0; index < matrix[indexV].length; index++) {
            if (matrix[indexV][index] == 1 && !this.visit[index]) {
                result = index;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    int[] bsf() {
        int[] result = new int[this.v.length];
        int[] indexes = new int[this.v.length];
        int cursor = 0;
        int count = 0;
        this.visit[count] = true;
        result[count] = this.v[count++];
        int nextIndex;

        while (count < result.length) {
            while ((nextIndex = getIndexNextV(indexes[cursor])) != -1) {
                this.visit[nextIndex] = true;
                indexes[count] = nextIndex;
                result[count++] = this.v[nextIndex];
            }
            cursor++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}

class GraphTest {
    private static final int[][] GRAPH = {
            {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
            {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, },
            {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, },
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, },
            {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, },
            {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, },
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, },
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, },
    };

    private static final int[] V = {2, 1, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 7};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graph g = new Graph(GRAPH, V);
        int[] result = g.bsf();
        System.out.println("Result graph: " + Arrays.toString(result));
    }
}
```

В данный класс я добавил свой граф и его матрицу смежности. Теперь думаю как мне заставить cursor запоминать последнее перемещение в пустую ячейку и уже из нее сортировать граф.

Comment: Мне кажется, это не очень подходящий алгоритм.

Comment: Форма графа всегда такая?

Comment: Тут всего 40320 перестановок - надо их брать вершинами, рёбер будет в 2 или 3 раза больше, bfs работает за O(n+m) и получится довольно шустренько.

Comment: @Qwertiy да форма графа всегда такая, есть 8 вершин из низ одна пустая.

Comment: @Qwertiy Сейчас думаю над реализацией топологической сортировки с поиском в глубину, вроде он тоже выполняется за  О(n+m). Я пока не понял как взять вершину с пустой ячейкой,  и запомнить последнюю перестановку.

Comment: @Qwertiy P.S.  вершин графа всегда 8, вершины могу принимать любые значения из диапазона от 0 до 7, например возможен граф 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

Comment: Ещё раз: бери граф из 40320 вершин, а не из 8.

Comment: @Qwertiy я что-то не могу понять как программно построить такой граф